# Store array of elements inside map function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to store my dates that i generated inside my map function, now it stores as array inside my **endDate**, i tried using forEach but it returns undefiened

here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-angular-starter-xetx4f?file=app/app.component.ts)

```
console.log(this.final); // ["2033-05-19T20:00:00.000Z", "2025-11-04T11:26:28.316Z"]

this.personalInfo = {
  personalInfoId: 0,
  underageChildInfo: this.data.underageChildInfo?.map((i) => ({
    firstName: i.name,
    endDate: this.final
  }))
};
```

Comment: `underageChildInfo` is a terrible property name fwiw.

Comment: Are you trying to store the endDates by index inside the underageChildInfo ? What is the output you're expecting ?

Comment: @Gray Hat Hi! endDate must have only one date not array of dates.

Comment: @Andy why? .....

Comment: I'm confused on what you're trying to do. You said `endDate` must have only one date and not an array. Under what condition do you extract this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be your solution then. Although here I'm assuming that your `this.final` has atleast `this.data.underageChildInfo?.length` values.

```
this.personalInfo = {
   personalInfoId: 0,
   underageChildInfo: this.data.underageChildInfo?.map((value,index) => ({
      firstName: value.name,
      endDate: this.final[index],
   })),
};
```